# giving a minimum size to dialog box in material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is it possible to give a minimum size to dialog box in material ui .I am rendering a react-calendar inside the dialog box but the entire calendar doesn't show up instead just a part of it is visible to the user. How can we assign a minimum size to the dialog box? 
This is the api of the [dialog](https://material-ui.com/api/dialog/)

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me

```
<Dialog
   maxWidth="md"
   fullWidth={true}
>
</Dialog>
```